# Why do I get a segmentation fault when the code tries to find a key in a STL Map?

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

Given an array *A[]* of integers. The task is to display the ordered pairs of 
positive integers `(X, Y)` such that X occurs in *A[]* at least Y times 
and Y occurs in A at least X times

e.g.input `A[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 }` -- the program runs fine with this input.
Ordered pairs are -> `{ [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2] }`

e.g. Input : A = { 3, 3, 2, 2, 2 } -- the program crashes with segmentation fault with this
Ordered pairs are -> `{ [3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3] }`

In function **getDesiredSet()**, at the below lines, the find fails with segmentation error.

`it1 = freqMap.find(itr->first);`
`it2 = freqMap.find(itr->second);`

```
# include "iostream"
# include "map"
# include "iterator"
# include "set"

using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> pairs;

map<int,int> getFreqMap(int arr[], int n){
map<int,int> freqMap;
map<int, int>::iterator it;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    //if( freqMap.find(arr[i]) != freqMap.end()){
    if (freqMap.count(arr[i])){
        it = freqMap.find(arr[i]);
        it->second = freqMap.count(arr[i]) + 1;
        freqMap[arr[i]] = freqMap.count(arr[i]) +1;
    }
    else{
        freqMap.insert(pair<int,int> (arr[i], 1) );
    }
}
cout << "\nFrequency Map - Element : Freq\n";
for (it = freqMap.begin(); it!= freqMap.end(); it++){
    cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;
}
return freqMap;
}

/* getPairSet finds out all the possible ordered pairs with the input numbers*/
/* and stores them in a set(so that there are no repeatation) */
set<pair<int,int> > getPairSet(int arr[], int n){
    set <pairs> s;//setOfPairs ;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<n-1; j++){
            pairs p = make_pair(arr[i],arr[j]);
            s.insert(p);
        }
    }
    set< pairs >:: iterator itr;
    cout << "\nPossible Pairs out of the given numbers in the array:\n";
    for (itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); itr++){
        cout <<"(" <<(*itr).first << "," << (*itr).second <<") " ;
    }
    return s;
}

/* getDesiredSet removes those order pairs which do match the criteria*/
/* in other words, it removes those order pairs in which */
/* either the frequency of 1st item is less than 2nd item */
/* or frequency of 2nd item is less than 1st item */
set<pairs > getDesiredSet(set<pairs > pairSet, map<int, int> freqMap){
    set<pairs > ::iterator itr, itrEnd;
    map<int, int>:: iterator it1, it2;
    for (itr = pairSet.begin(); itr != pairSet.end(); itr++){
        it1 = freqMap.find(itr->first);
        it2 = freqMap.find(itr->second);
        if ((it1->second < itr->second) || (it2->second < itr->first)){
            itrEnd = itr;
            std::advance(itrEnd , 1);
            pairSet.erase(itr, itrEnd);
        }
    }
    return pairSet;
}

int main(){
map<int, int> freqMap;
int arr[] = { 3, 3, 2, 2, 2 };
cout << "\nInput Array Elements:\n";
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
for (int z=0; z< n; z++)
    cout << arr[z] << " ";
freqMap = getFreqMap(arr, n);
set<pair<int,int> > pairSet = getPairSet(arr,n);
set<pair<int,int> > desiredSet = getDesiredSet(pairSet, freqMap);
set<pair<int,int> > :: iterator itr;
cout << "\n\nDesired order pairs\n";
for (itr = desiredSet.begin(); itr != desiredSet.end(); itr++){
    cout <<"(" <<(*itr).first << "," << (*itr).second <<") " ;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the erase the iterator is invalid but you use it next loop turn, here :

```
for (itr = pairSet.begin(); itr != pairSet.end(); itr++){
    it1 = freqMap.find(itr->first);
    it2 = freqMap.find(itr->second);
    if ((it1->second < itr->second) || (it2->second < itr->first)){
        itrEnd = itr;
        std::advance(itrEnd , 1);
        pairSet.erase(itr, itrEnd); << itr is invalid now
    }
}
```

To detect invalid memory accesses or memory leap *valgrind* is a very practical free tool, if you can use it.

Comment: Thank you. How can I fix the issue, as I can not use erase to remove an element from the map.

Comment: look at the link given in the remarks (possible duplicate), if you still don't understand ask me again :)